# Using of lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am writing to ask about what is the difference between lambda expression and equal sign in this example:

```
public string Id => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"];
```

And:

```
public string Id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"];
```

Or there is no difference?

Answer (score 3):

The first statement isn't a lambda, it's an [expression-body definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition) (valid starting from C# 6)

```cs
public string Id => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"];
```

Yo can apply it to methods, properties, indexers, per [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

It's just a more readable form (without `get` and `return`) of readonly property

```cs
public string Id
{
    get
    {
         return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"];
    }
}
```

The second one is usual assignment, initializes the `Id` field

Answer (score 2):

```
public string Id => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"];
```

This is not a lambda expression, but an expression bodied property. The AppSetting will be read whenever the getter of the property is invoked.

```
public string Id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"];
```

This simply declares a public field and initializes it once when the instance is constructed. The AppSetting value will only be read at this time.